# Centralized pages control in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I have 20 pages in a module in power Bi. Each page have some similarities for example background color. If I want to change background color I have to change in every page. Is there any way to control all pages centrally?. For example I want to change background color in one page and all the other pages will take the reference from that page and change automatically?

I do not have much idea about power bi. I am just asking whether it’s possible or not

Comment: Read about Report Themes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-report-themes

Comment: Just make supplement based on David: You should set background color with 'Theme Color' not the custom color you input color code. Then change the 'Theme Color' you used as background color under 'View' menu followed by the link David showed you.